# Use custom domain with S3 and cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront

So I'm trying to use an alternate domain name in CloudFront. Let's say `www.example.com`.

1. I created an S3 bucket with all public access blocked. Under the
   policy I gave permission to my CloudFront distribution to access the
   contents of the bucket, and enabled the bucket to "host a static
   website".
2. Under the domain name for the CloudFront distribution, I'm using the
   bucket endpoint with `Origin access control settings (recommended)`
   on.
3. Now, up to this point this seems to work. If I go to the
   distribution domain name, my website is loaded. I'm only getting
   problems loading from my custom domain name.
4. So next, I set up the alternate domain name, and I added a custom
   SSL certificate. I validated the certificate by adding a dns record
   to my dns domain database (I'm using Google Domains).
5. Finally, I set up a cname record from my domain `www.example.com` to
   go to my CloudFront distribution, but this is where it's failing. I
   just get `This site can't be reached The sever IP address could not be found`

What am I doing wrong? Do I need a different type of record with the CloudFront distribution? Also it's been over 72hr since last time I updated the dns records, so I don't expect that to be an issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CloudFront doesn't support assigning a static IP address to distributions, that's why you have to use **Amazon Route 53** to create an **alias** record that points to your **CloudFront distribution**.

In order to run your website exposed with CloudFront with your own domain, you have to do the following things.

- Point your domain from other domain registrar *i.e. GoDaddy* to Route53.

  - Create a hosted zone in **Route53** for your apex domain *i.e. example.com* or sub-domain *i.e. abc.example.com*
  - Once created, copy the 4 NS records of the new hosted zone to your GoDaddy domain. This causes your domain to use Route53 name-servers going forward.
- Select you newly created hosted zone, create an **A** record with **Alias** enabled, and select your **CloudFront** distribution from the dropdown.
- To create an **ACM certificate**, select **us-east-1 (north virginia)** region, as **CloudFront** certificates needs to be created only in this region.
- Use **DNS Validation** when provisioning the certificate using ACM, it takes some time to validate the domain. But if your domain is configured correctly, it will pass the validation in roughly 5 minutes.